# How to inject a Spring bean into a Seam context?

Tags: java, spring, seam

I need to inject a Spring bean into a Seam context. Unless I declare the spring bean as a EJB, I cannot get it injected into other seam-managed components. But when I do this, all the spring injected fields are usless cause Seam creates new instances at run-time.

I also tried to add the `<seam:component/>` element to the spring bean definition and tried to inject it in the container with the `@In("beanId")` annotation in the target class but I always end up with a NullpointerException...

**EDIT:**

I read the online articles and did as they say. My spring component is also added to the seam context (I can tell, cause when I define one with the same ID in seam, it complains). Looks like `@In` is not picking up....

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: How do you test your app ? Are you using SeamTest with embedded JBoss Embedded server ?

Comment: @Arthur: Lots of unit tests, automated tests through the UI layer with an external app on top of selenium. Some integration tests that pull up the spring context, not the seam though... maybe a good idea to isolate the problem, have a look at the seam context.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read [this chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/spring.html)? It should tell you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Raoul,

Although i do not use Seam along with Spring, [chapter 15](http://www.manning.com/dallen/SeamIACH15_bonus.pdf) of Seam In Action books talks about Spring integration. It is free and is updated.

You have said

> I also tried to add the  element to the spring bean definition and tried to inject it in the container with the @In("beanId")

Seam in Action book says

> The EL expression used in the @In annotation, #{tournamentManager}, resolves to an equivalently named bean in the Spring container, courtesy of the delegating variable resolver

Do you have to use @In("#{beanId}") instead of @In("beanId"), do not ?

I have seen

By default, <seam:component/> will create a STATELESS Seam component **with class and name** provided in the bean definition.

```
<bean id="someSpringBean" class="SomeSpringBeanClass" scope="prototype">
    <seam:component/>
</bean>
```

And

> The scope attribute of <seam:component/> may be used if you wish the Spring bean to be
>   managed in a particular Seam scope. The Spring bean **must be scoped to prototype** if the
>   Seam scope specified **is anything other than STATELESS**.

Have you done as above ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a project using Seam + Spring and I have to set @In(create=true) when I want to inject a Spring bean into my Seam component otherwise I get a NullPointerException, you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as yours. I followed strictly the "Chapter 27. Spring Framework integration" in seam ref. document. But my spring bean was never got injected to seam component. And finally, I found out I had the @BypassInterceptors in my seam component. By removing that annotation, my spring bean was successfully injected. Then I realized that, dependency injection is handled by seam BijectionInterceptor. Thus, the @BypassInterceptors will effectively bypass this filter :)